# sharepoint 2013 approval workflow approvers from another list

Tags: list, 2013, workflow

I have a SharePoint 2013 farm and Workflow2013.

My boss want me to make an approval Workflow where approvers come from a SharePoint list.

I googled it but i couldn't find a solution for Workflow 2013.

Let me clerify the issue.

When a form submitted, it goes the first degree aprrover. If it is approved it goes second degree approver.

Approvers come from a basic sharepoint list(not sophisticated). There is one item with 2 columns(approvers).

Answer (score 1):

I solve my case with winding way.

I create 3 text box in my infopath form. And add the list connection with the list where my approvers store.  And configure their default value and then hide.
in sharepoint designer i chose approvers as current item' first approver.

Comment: Do you have any idea about how to do same task in visual studio ? With workflow manager ?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to create few variables using SharePoint designer and assign them dynamically as explained in this article.

> Begin with setting a new workflow variable by querying the
>   corresponding approvers. Act like the following description (depending
>   on your list setup of step I):
>
> Set a new workflow variable with the unique id of your item. Set a
>   second workflow variable and use the first variable, go into the list
>   where your approvers are stored, look up the id and select the
>   approver. Of course both variables have to have name – store them as
>   string (If you have more than one child/parent relationship between
>   your lists you may to repeat this steps).
>
> In our pictured example we first have a variable with an ID. The
>   second Variable queries the list “Divisions” and filters the
>   responsible persons (storing the display names) by using the first
>   variable to go through the list and stopping at the correct position.
>
> Please note that it is necessary to have a clear understanding of your
>   list setup, having correct relationships and unique identifiers. To
>   prove your workflow set up you can log the results of the variable
>   queries in the workflow history list (there is an action for that in
>   the SPD2010).

[SharePoint 2010: dynamic approvers in standard approval workflow (pt II)](http://blogs.tieto.com/futureoffice/2013/08/14/sharepoint-2010-dynamic-approvers-in-standard-approval-workflow-pt-ii/)

Off course this is part two but you can check out part-I for more clarifications.

Comment: thanks for reply. how can i set a workflow variable by query

Comment: are you allowed to use Visual Studio to create a solution in this scenario ?

Comment: no. i should use only designer 2013.

Comment: I'm taking this error internal status. http://postimg.org/image/ddmed7v9t/